# Why does java.util.Collection.remove() return a boolean?

Tags: java, collections

Are there any real world examples of when a caller might use the value returned from [`Collection.remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29)?

I'm happy that the method returns a boolean but am struggling to think of a case when the result would be useful to a caller.

Comment: Simplest use is to perform a check, `if(Collection.remove(Obj)){ do some operation; }` likewise with the other functions.

Comment: It saves time over having to check `contains` and then call `remove`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the javadoc says

> Removes a **single instance** of the specified element from this collection, if it is present (optional operation).

The collection might contain multiple objects that are all equal, because a collection is not  necessarily a Set.

So one use case might be to remove all instances of an object equal to the remove argument.

```
while(col.remove(anObject));
```

Remember that the javadoc also says:

> More formally, removes an element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))

So if you get a collection that might contain null values and you only want to process the "real" objects, you can make this code easier

```
for(Object obj : col) {
    if(obj != null){
        doSomethingWithObject(obj);
    }
}
```

by removing the `null` values first:

```
while(col.remove(null));

for(Object obj : col) {
    doSomethingWithObject(obj); 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[`Collection.remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) returns `false` when the object passed to it was *not* found in the collection.

That sounds fairly useful to me, especially if you expected the object to be there - once removed it would be impossible to confirm that it previously was. The call to `remove()` is the last chance to discover it wasn't there.

Comment: Or maybe you might need to deregister some object if it was contained in the `Collection`, but it's not a problem if someone tries to remove an object that wasn't there in the first place.

Comment: @chrylis right. whatever the reason of needing to know, you can only find out while calling `remove()`